# Does Doctrine/PHP integration offer Autocomplete in IDE?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, autocomplete, phpdoc, zend-studio

Using PHP + Doctrine I get this:

```
    //retrieve data
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
    $all = $entityManager->getRepository('\Entity\ServiceType')->findAll();
    foreach($all as $value)
        $options[$value->getId()] = $value->getServiceType();
```

Autocomplete within IDE does not suggest methods that follow `->`, namely things like `getId()`, and `getServiceType()`.

And PHP does not offer (easy) casting to desired type....

Comment: which ide are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work (v12.5):

```
    foreach ($all as $key => $value)
        /**
         * @var $value ServiceType
         */
        $options[$value->getId()] = $value->getId();
```

This appears to work as well (v13.0):

```
    /**
     * @var $all ServiceType
     */
    foreach ($all as $key => $value)
       $options[$value->getId()] = $value->getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to **typehint** for the IDE to know what type of model the repository reutrns.

The `getRepository` method returns a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`, which, when calling `findAll()` has no idea what type of entity it is you are trying to find (while find all returns a `array`).

```
/** @var \Entity\ServiceType[] $all */
$all = $entityManager->getRepository('\Entity\ServiceType')->findAll();
```

Should do the trick.

---

Edit:
Apparently not all IDE's support this. 
If that is the case, you can create a typehint comment inside the foreach loop for the `$value` variant instead:

```
/** @var \Entity\ServiceType[] $all */
$all = $entityManager->getRepository('\Entity\ServiceType')->findAll();
foreach($all as $value) {
    /** @var \Entity\ServiceType $value */
    $options[$value->getId()] = $value->getServiceType();
}
```

First hint for any of the devs in the team that uses the Jetbrains IDEs and the second for the rest!

Comment: did not work for `$all`, but did for `$value`

Comment: Sorry for that, edited the comment to look as it should. I.E., its an `array`, so the `[]` is required for it to be hinted as a list of `ServiceType` objects.

Comment: well ... tried all of them but does not work for all... still

Comment: Ah, it might be a limitation in Zend studio. Then your typehint on the `$value` solution should work. The above solution should work fine in any of the jetbrains php IDE's though. :)